# How to incrementally print to GUI using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, printing, pyinstaller

I want to print out incrementally the progress of my `main` function in the GUI using tkinter. Because I'm planning to package my python code in `.exe` file using PyInstaller and my users won't like reading the logs in a console.

Here I wrote my codes but currently there are two problems.

1. The newest text overwrites on the top of the previous one. So I cannot see the past texts.
2. The text is printed only when the entire function is finished running. So now there's around one minute of computation time and when it's finished, it just displays the last text `Job 3 done`.

---

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry('600x600')
tk.Label(master, text="days").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, text="coefficients").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(master, text="log").grid(row=5)
e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e1.insert(10, 0)
e2.insert(10, 0.5)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

lower_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg='#80c1ff', bd='5')
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')
lower_label = tk.Label(lower_frame)
lower_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

def main():
    # do job 1
    lower_label.config(text="Job 1 done")
    
    # do job 2
    lower_label.config(text="Job 2 done")

    # do job 3
    lower_label.config(text="Job 3 done")

b = tk.Button(master, text="run", command=main).grid(row=3, 
                                                     column=1, 
                                                     sticky=tk.W, 
                                                     pady=4)

master.mainloop()
tk.mainloop()
```

My my code currently outputs on GUI

```
 _______________
|   Job 3 done  |
|_______________|
```

My expected behaviour

```
 _______________
|   Job 1 done  |
|   Job 2 done  |
|   Job 3 done  |
|_______________|
```

How can I fix this? Problem 2 is less important than the 1 so I would like to at least find a solution for the problem 1. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Why are you using the Label widget for the log? I'd choose the Text widget instead. The 1st problem is solved easily then. Considering the 2nd problem, the jobs are pausing the Tkinter mainloop, so it doesn't take the control back in time and doesn't update the widgets automatically, and you do not update the label after every job manually. Due to the same reason, the app does not respond while any job is running. Perhaps multithreading can help you solve this problem, although it depends on what are the jobs like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because tkinter mainloop has not taken the control back so the changes on the label is not updated.  You need to call `lower_label.update()` after each change to force the update.

For your case, it is better to use `Text` instead of `Label`:

```
lower_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg='#80c1ff', bd='5')
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

log_box = tk.Text(lower_frame, state='disabled')
log_box.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

def log(msg):
    log_box.config(state='normal')
    log_box.insert('end', msg+'\n')
    log_box.see('end')
    log_box.config(state='disabled')
    log_box.update()

def main():
    # do job 1
    log("Job 1 done")
    
    # do job 2
    log("Job 2 done")

    # do job 3
    log("Job 3 done")
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Yes it was better to use Text instead of Label.

Answer (score 0):

Change the body of your `main()` function to:

```
lower_label.config(text="Starting jobs...")
master.update()

import time    
time.sleep(2)  # do job 1

lower_label.config(text="Job 1 done.")
master.update()

time.sleep(2)  # do job 2

lower_label.config(text=lower_label['text'] + "\nJob 2 done.")
master.update()

time.sleep(2)  # do job 3

lower_label.config(text=lower_label['text'] + "\nJob 3 done.")
master.update()
```

The reason only "Job 3 done" was showing up is because you overwrite the label text each time with something new, until the final text is used (which is not overwritten).  So I made it reuse the previous text while appending to it the new text you wanted.

**Important point:**  You'll notice that I write `master.update()` right after I update the label.  If I didn't, you wouldn't see any text changes until the `main()` function finishes.